# FB com plugin using angularjs and html5?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments

I am using fb comment plugin with angularjs and html5. it opens in a modal window on a link click. all works fine but when someone else comments on it, it doesnt appear automatically on my window. it needs to be refreshed. I want it to be dynamic

Code used is:

```
<div class="fb-comments"
             data-href="http://pingle.in?postId={{postresult.id}}" data-width="550px" data-numposts="5"
             data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```